# How do make a sidebar show icon of the list when it is toggled? i am using bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a simple bootstrap 4 navbar with a sidebar also and when I toggle it, the whole sidebar is hidden is there a way to make it show only the icons of the list the sidebar has?

Comment: please provide more info like adding your code or upload it and put the url in here

Answer (score 0):

you can reduce the element width instead of hiding it with animation and align your icons to the left side of your sidebar

```
javascript:

<script>
$("#your-button").click(function(){
   $("#your-sidebar").toggleClass('sidebar-close');
});
</script>

Css:

<style>
.sidebar-close{
    width: 32px!important; /* your icon size */
}
</style>
```

you have to attach jquery to your page if you use bootstrap it possible you already include it
jquery CDN link:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: do i have to create a class called "sidebar-close"?

Comment: yes, you can create any class name you want and put it in the toggleClass function

Comment: like this ``` .your-class{width: 32px!important;}  ``` and  ``` $("#your-sidebar").toggleClass('your-class'); ```

Comment: i mean in the html part. do i need a class called "sidebar-close" in the html? and if so what does it have to include?

Comment: yes, you do. I have written what you need to include in it in my answer

Comment: i added the javascript and the css, i also copied the CDN link but it doesn't work

Comment: make sure you added CDN in the head tag and your script in bottom of the body and add use correct element id for jquery selector